# Finite-codimension subalgebras of generalized Kac-Moody lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Do [generalized Kac-Moody lie algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Kac%E2%80%93Moody_algebra) of infinite dimension contain subalgebras of finite codimension? If so, is there a classification?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "finite index"?  Do you mean "finite codimension"?

Comment: Yes, finite codimension as a vector space. Is there another possible interpretation?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.   Usually "finite index" has meaning only in a group-theoretic context.

Comment: Right, I think this was just a typo on my part.

Comment: Beware (in contrast to the group setting) that the existence of a proper finite-codimensional subalgebra does not imply that of such an ideal. For instance Amayo  (Quasi-ideals of Lie algebras II, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 33, 1976, 37-64) constructed an infinite-dimensional simple Lie algebra with a subalgebra of codimension 1.